# Simple silverlight mouse event question

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

A simple silverlight app:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Canvas x:Name="C1" MouseLeftButtonDown="C1_MouseLeftButtonDown" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Canvas x:Name="C2" MouseLeftButtonDown="C2_MouseLeftButtonDown" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Rectangle x:Name="R1" Fill="AliceBlue" Height="40" Width="60"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Why do the Canvas mouse event handlers get called only when I click in the Rectangle control, and not in the empty Canvas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the Canvas a background brush to give the Canvas a surface on which to detect a mouse.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"> 
    <Canvas x:Name="C1" Background="White" MouseLeftButtonDown="C1_MouseLeftButtonDown" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"> 
        <Canvas x:Name="C2" MouseLeftButtonDown="C2_MouseLeftButtonDown" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"> 
            <Rectangle x:Name="R1" Fill="AliceBlue" Height="40" Width="60"/> 
        </Canvas> 
    </Canvas> 
</Grid>
```